# Add custom attribute to filter in product collection in magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to add custom attribute to filter for product collection

I tried below code but filter is not working

```
$_productCollections=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection = $_productCollections->addAttributeToFilter('weight', array('lt' => 100));
```

below code is working

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$_productCollection = $collection->addAttributeToFilter('weight', array('lt' => 100));
```

I need proper way to add filter range for weight attribute like

```
->addAttributeToFilter('weight', array('lt' => 100));
```

in default product collection(`$this->getLoadedProductCollection();`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have one solution for this question

Step1:

Duplicate block code for list

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php to 
\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php
```

Step2:

Change below code from

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
```

to

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('weight', array('lt' => 100));
```

This is one simple solution to resolve your issue properly.

Comment: This will likely have implications for the price filter, which clones the product collection from here and resets its "FROM" parts, resulting in Magento trying to retrieve `weight` in this case from one of the price index tables. It's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try explicitly selecting the attribute with:

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('weight');
```

And then the filtering:

```
$_productCollections->addAttributeToFilter('weight', array('lt' => 100));
```

Another way is selecting by default the attribute in the product collection, by placing this in the config.xml of your module:

```
<config>
<frontend>
     <product>
          <collection>
               <attributes>
                  <weight />
               </attributes>
          </collection>
      </product>
</frontend>
```

Then you should be able to do the filter as usual:

```
$_productCollections->addAttributeToFilter('weight', array('lt' => 100));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, collection is already loaded. Add filter before loading collection

`($this->_getProductCollection()->load())`